# Convert an object to a type based on the string value passed in C#

Tags: c#, .net, object, types, casting

I have a requirement where the object type [name of the object] is passed as a string variable. Now based on the object name passed, I need to create that object type. Please note the string value contains the exact object type name. I have written a code snippet but it is throwing an exception.

e.g -

```
string objectName = "EntityTest.Entity.OrderEntity";//Entity type name
object obj = new object();
object newobj = new object();
newobj = Convert.ChangeType(obj, Type.GetType(objectName));
```

I do this I get error -- > `Object must implement IConvertible.`

My entity `OrderEntity` has already implemented the `IConvertible` interface.

Any help/suggestion is greatly appreciated. Is there any other way I can create the object to fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 9):

You're currently trying to convert an *existing* object, rather than creating one of the right type. Assuming your `Type.GetType` call is working, you can just use:

```
Type type = Type.GetType(objectName);
object x = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

A few points to note:

- `Type.GetType(string)` requires an assembly-qualified name *unless* the type is either in the currently-executing assembly or `mscorlib`
- [`Activator.CreateInstance(Type)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wccyzw83.aspx) will call the parameterless constructor (which has to be accessible); if you need to pass arguments to the constructor, there are [other overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) available.

Comment: this is great but then how we can pass value into new generated object?

Comment: @HamedZakeryMiab: Do you mean you want to call a parameterized constructor? You could either call `type.GetConstructors()`, find the right constructor and invoke it, or use one of the overloads for `Activator.CreateInstance` that allows you to specify arguments. Try those, and if you run into problems, start a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you're creating an instance of `object` and then trying to cast that to a more specific type (which it can't be).

You need a way to call the default constructor of the type that you're trying to create. Take a look at [`Activator.CreateInstance()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx):

```
var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

If the type has no default constructor, the above example will fail. In that case, your best bet is probably to [use this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx) (that takes an array of objects to use as constructor parameters and then tries to find the best match)